# How can I limit the depth to search in a convoluted graph that has a goal node

Tags: graph, graph-algorithm, depth-first-search, state-machine

I have convoluted graph that I need to search. After searching, the paths that are found needs to always end with the goal node. This node has no other deeper nodes. Furthermore, the length of the paths will be limited, so before reaching the limit, it has to find the goal node. I have an example graph:
[graph example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W22n2.png)
In this case, for the following limits I would expect the results next to them.

- 2 => nothing
- 3 or 4 => I,1,F
- 6 => I,2,3,I,1,F and all of the above
- 7 or 8 => I,1,2,3,I,1,F and all of the above
- 9 => I,2,3,I,2,3,I,1,F and all of the above

Once I increase the limit more, I would get more loops and so on. I know that depth first search would work for me with the goal state but I don't know how to take the limit into account in a *smart way*. I can do the search and then stop it if the depth limit is reached. Is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: @Did I answer your question? If so, please accept the answer and if not please comment.

Answer (score 0):

There is also iterative deepening DFS, which you can use. [See Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_deepening_depth-first_search)

It is nothing crazy, you just path your desired limit to DFS algorithm and each time you go down you will decrease the limit; once you hit 0 your depth has reached and you can't go any further.

Comment: Thank you! This is more or less what I have done. I have searched until hitting zero and backtraced afterwards to find unvisited nodes. I just did it before reading your answer though :)